# can i search google cloud storage buckets recursively in the console?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have uploaded files to google cloud storage buckets and planning to create a permission to have a number of people access it.  So far we could only filter/search files and folders in the directory you are in. Is it possible to search files recursively though?

Answer (score 6):

It seems what you are looking for is the following command for searching within a bucket recursively:

```
gsutil ls -r gs://bucket/**
```

*Note:  "**bucket**" is the name of the bucket you have set.*

In the case you would like to search within a specific directory you can run the following:

`gsutil ls -r gs://bucket/dir/**`

*Note:  **"dir"** would be the directory in which you would like to search*

You can find more information regarding searching through "Directory By Directory, Flat, And Recursive" by going to the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls#directory-by-directory-flat-and-recursive-listings).

---

***Update***

If this is **not** what you meant then I would like to mention another option. You can retrieve the information regarding the contents in a bucket through an API as well. The following API link [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list?apix_params=%7B%22bucket%22%3A%22test-bucket-harmit%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%7D) retrieves a list of objects matching the criteria specified.

*Note: In order for this API to work the user must have "**READER**" permission or above.*

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, we have regular users who only have access to the GUI. We're looking to see if there's a way on the GUI to filter recursively.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. my gsutil version is 5.5, which is new. and `gsutil ls  gs://build-bucket/` works currently, but `gsutil ls -r gs://build-bucket/**` doesn't.